# How to sort on a field that is encrypted using the attr_encrypted gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, attr-encrypted

I am currently using attr_encrypted gem to encrypt content so that only users that have a certain key can see portions of documents available to a broader group. Everything works fine until I try to sort the list on one of the encrypted fields. I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) several times and experimented several way to no avail.

In the CommunityMember model:

```
attr_encrypted :last_name, :key => :encryption_key
```

In the controller I have tried

```
@list = CommunityMember.order("last_name")
AND
@list = CommunityMember.order("encrypted_#{last_name}")
AND
@list = CommunityMember.order("encrypted_#{'last_name'}")
```

None produced the desired result. Thanks for your help.

Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sort_by](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/enumerable#method-i-sort_by) method

```rb
@list = CommunityMember.all.sort_by(&:last_name)
```